# PHP and Exists SQLITE

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

To insert data, update data and delete table is it necessary to copy the existing sqlite database into :memory: in PHP?

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [appointment] (
    _appId integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
   ,_id integer NOT NULL
   ,svc_id integer NOT NULL
   ,cust_id integer NOT NULL
   ,person_nm text NOT NULL
   ,cust_cno integer NOT NULL
   ,full_add text NOT NULL
   ,book_dt date NOT NULL
   ,app_dt date NOT NULL
   ,app_time time NOT NULL
   ,service text NOT NULL
   ,status text NOT NULL
   ,nxt_dt date
   ,nxt_time time
   ,att_dt date
   ,att_time time
   ,remark text
);
```

and Update statement is:

```
UPDATE appointment 
SET svc_id='$sid',app_dt='$dt',app_time='$tim',full_add='$add',cust_cno='$cno' 
WHERE _appId='$i';
```

Comment: Table definition: Check. Update statement: Check.  Question: Uh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can access and change SQLite database stored in a file directly.

Comment: Thank you so much..But i have a problem while updating the table. It cannot get updated into database. Can you help me please...

Comment: @Yogi - please include your table definition and `UPDATE` statement

Comment: @dezso-Table definition:CREATE TABLE [appointment] (_appId integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,_id integer NOT NULL,svc_id integer NOT NULL,cust_id integer NOT NULL,person_nm text NOT NULL,cust_cno integer NOT NULL,full_add text NOT NULL,book_dt date NOT NULL,app_dt date NOT NULL,app_time time NOT NULL,service text NOT NULL,status text NOT NULL,nxt_dt date,nxt_time time,att_dt date,att_time time,remark text); and Update statement is: UPDATE appointment SET svc_id='$sid',app_dt='$dt',app_time='$tim',full_add='$add',cust_cno='$cno' where _appId='$i'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Yogi - Does your update work from an SQLite console?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: @dezso: It work from SQLite manager. I do not get any errors

Comment: Hmm... do you have write permissions on the db file? Script might not have them.